# Transitions triggered on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Am trying to clone this[https://imdev.in/] portfolio website for practice. And I saw these cool transitions that are triggered on scrolling, from what I understand. Like when you scroll through, the navbar, previously transparent, becomes dark.
I'd love to learn how to do that, so any input is much appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need is to make use of the [scroll function in jquery](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) or on scroll event of javascript. So whenever the user scrolls you can change the css of your navbar or simply add or remove a new class to it. You can use [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#nav) to create flexible navigation bars with many pre built css classes. Here is the javascript code that will work perfectly for you.

```
 $(function () {
$(document).scroll(function () {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > $("#topNav").height()){
        $("#topNav").addClass("bg-dark");
        $("#topNav").addClass("navbar-dark");
        $("#topNav").removeClass("bg-light");
        $("#topNav").removeClass("navbar-light");
    }
    else{
        $("#topNav").addClass("bg-light");
        $("#topNav").addClass("navbar-light");
        $("#topNav").removeClass("bg-dark");
        $("#topNav").removeClass("navbar-dark");
    }
    });
});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ankitram/vcmoL6zp/6/) to test the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You would add an event listener on the window object, something like so:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', animate)

  function animate() {
    // Logic to add animation here
  }
```